# R: Inverse of factor interaction

Tags: r, interaction, split

I'm having a great deal of trouble with the following problem, and can't seem to find an answer with extensive searching.  If I have the following:

```
> fac1 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))
> fac2 <- factor(c("d", "e", "f"))
> fac3 <- interaction(fac1,fac2)
> fac3

[1] a.d b.e c.f
Levels: a.d b.d c.d a.e b.e c.e a.f b.f c.f
```

What function can I run to split fac3 so that I obtain the levels of the original factors put into the interaction? So that:

```
> myFun(fac3, 1)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c"
> myFun(fac3, 2)
[2] "d" "d" "d" "e" "e" "e" "f" "f" "f"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
> myFun <- function(fac, idx) sapply( strsplit(as.character(fac), "\\."), "[", idx)
> myFun(fac3,1)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
> myFun(fac3,2)
[1] "d" "e" "f"
```

Depending on what you wanted to do with these vectors you could wrap factor() around the results. There is some ambiguity in your question. Looking at @user1317221's contribution I see that it does return what you said you wanted but when you said you wanted the levels of the factor, I thought you wanted vectors only as long as 'fac3' which had three elements, despite having a longer levels attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  strsplit was the core thing I was hunting for, but the "[" bit as a function in sapply is new to me as well.

Comment: Yeah. Learning to think about "[" as an infix function is a little different, I'll admit.

Comment: I think that I'm just trained to see an open bracket without a close as a problem waiting to happen.  The function you provided is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The parser converts  `object[arg1, arg2]` into `'['(object, arg1, arg2)`   see `?Extract`. So it is handling the [] pair as a function of the item immediately preceding the open-bracket and the items within the enclosing brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily turn the following into a function

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(fac3), "\\."), "[", 1)
sapply(strsplit(as.character(fac3), "\\."), "[", 2)
```